# I am getting the below error when trying to run tests in Karate Junit5

Tags: karate, junit5

Error : **java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.intuit.karate.core.ExecutionContext.(JLcom/intuit/karate/core/FeatureContext;Lcom/intuit/karate/CallContext;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/function/Consumer;Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;)V**

///

package tests;

import com.intuit.karate.junit5.Karate;

public class test{

```
@Karate.Test
public Karate test()
{
    return new Karate().feature("featurefile").relativeTo(getClass());


}
```

}
///

Answer (score 0):

Wow that sounds like a really old version. Here are 2 suggestions for you:

1. If you are new to programming and Java, use the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release
2. Or please follow these instructions: https://youtu.be/W-af7Cd8cMc

If you are still stuck, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue